# Anyway to avoid floating point operation for Max Points on Line problem

Tags: c++, precision, computational-geometry

I'm trying to solve "Max Points on Line" problem on Leet code. I inevitably need to do floating point operation to calculation Y-Intercept and slope of each line. Due to my past bad experience, I'm trying to avoid floating point operations as much as I can. Do you have any suggestion how I can do that here?

I am using LeetCode framework for development and pretty much just have access to standard C++ library.
Tried using double or long double but one of the test cases already pushes the numbers to the limits of the accuracy of these data types.

```
//P1[0] is X coordinate for point P1 and P1[1] is Y coordinate

long double slopeCalc( vector<int> &p1, vector<int> &p2 )
{
    if( p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] == p2[1] )
    {
        return DBL_MIN;
    }

    if( p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] != p2[1] )
    {
        return DBL_MAX;
    }

    return ( (long double)p2[1] - (long double)p1[1] ) / ((long double)p2[0] - (long double)p1[0]);
}

long double yIntersectionCalc( vector<int> &p1, vector<int> &p2 )
{
    if( p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] == p2[1] )
    {
        return DBL_MIN;
    }

    if( p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] != p2[1] )
    {
        return DBL_MAX;
    }

    return ((long double)p1[1]*(long double)p2[0] - (long double)p2[1]*(long double)p1[0]) / (long double)(p2[0] - p1[0]);        
}
```

If the two points are (0, 0) and (94911150, 94911151) the slope is calculated as 1 which is inaccurate. I'm trying to avoid the floating point division if possible.

NOTE: Max Points on a Line problem is to be given points in 2D space (in this case integer coordinates) and find the maximum number of points that are on one line. E.g if the points are (0,0), (2,2), (4,3), (1,1) the answer is 3 which are points (0,0), (1,1), and (2,2)

Comment: Please describe the "Max Points on Line" problem in your question.

Comment: I added a brief description of the problem at the end of my post.

Answer (score 2):

In integer coordinates, the alignment test of three points can be written as the expression

```
(Xb - Xa) (Yc  - Ya) - (Yb - Ya) (Xc - Xa) = 0
```

Assuming that the range of the coordinates requires `N` bits, the computation of the deltas takes `N+1` bits, and exact evaluation of the expression takes `2N+2` bits at worse. There is little that you can do against that.

In your case, 64 bits integers should be enough.

---

A piece of advice: avoid working with the slope/intercept representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using floating point, what you can do to determine if a point z is collinear with two other points x and y is to compute the determinant of the matrix

```
{{1,z1,z2},{1,x1,x2},{1,y1,y2}}
```

If the determinant is 0, then they are collinear. Since computing the determinant using the permutation definition involves only multiplication and addition/subtraction, all your computations will remain as integers. The reason it will be 0 is that the determinant is twice the area of the triangle with x,y,z as vertices,which is zero if and only if the triangle is degenerate.

Another approach would be to use Fraction objects, in particular the slope and the intercept  of the lines defined by two integers are identified as Fractions ("rational numbers"), and a reduced fraction is identified by its numerator and denominator, so you can use the pair of fractions (slope,intercept) as identifiers and since you never use floating point arithmetic you won't need to deal with roundoff error. See https://martin-thoma.com/fractions-in-cpp/ for a sample implementation of Fractions, the important part is that you can use the arithmetic operators, and normalization.

EDIT: boost has a rational number library, if you want to use it https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/rational/

Comment: The problem though is that I have to find another solution to the original problem I was trying to solve. I need something to define the characteristic of the line. Something in the form of slope and Y-intercept which can be a key to find the line in a dictionary. 2 or 3 points on a line can't be used as a key to find info about the number of points on the line.

Comment: If you want to define it in terms of the slope and the intercept, note that both have to be fractions. So you can define a Fraction class , overloading the arithmetic operators for the class, AND keeping the fractions in reduced form.

Comment: There are plenty of implementations of a Fraction class out there, i would recommend searching for one you like, or implementing one yourself if you want the practice. Here is one to get you started: https://martin-thoma.com/fractions-in-cpp/

Answer (score 0):

Given points `a,b,c`, look at the slopes `b,c` make to a common point, `a`:

```
ba.x = b.x - a.x
ba.y = b.y - a.y

ba.s = ba.y / ba.x

ca.x = c.x - a.x
ca.y = c.y - a.y

ca.s = ca.y / ca.x
```

The points `a,b,c` are co-linear iff the lines `AB` and `BC` have a common slope, i.e.:

```
ba.s == ca.s
```

Substituting and rearranging to remove the divides:

```
ba.y / ba.x == ca.y / ca.x
ba.y * ca.x / ba.x == ca.y
ba.y * ca.x == ca.y * ba.x
```

Substitute in the original formulas for those, then `a,b,c` are co-linear iff:

```
(b.y - a.y) * (c.x - a.x) == (c.y - a.y) * (b.x - a.x)
```

Note that the determinant answer could also be rearranged into this form which proves this approach. But this form has just 2 multiplications rather than 12 for a naive determinant implementation.